# How to match UTF8 characters in MySQL regular expression?

Tags: mysql, regex, utf-8

So I want to find out all the rows that has UTF8 characters in a specific field, in this manner:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 REGEXP '[[:utf8:]]';
```

Searched through MySQL docs but found nothing. Is this possible?

Comment: What does  "UTF8 characters" mean in this context - multi-byte ones?

Comment: what exactly do you want to match? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant **non-ASCII** characters.

Managed to find a way to do that: http://www.kavoir.com/2011/03/mysql-find-non-ascii-characters.html